# error in Next.js 13 with app directory for importing wagmi package: Package path ./dist/chains is not exported from package

Tags: next.js, wagmi

Next.js 13 with app directory with client component.
I have problem in importing *hardhat*.

[image]

component code:

```js
"use client";

import { Faucet } from "./scaffold-eth";
import { hardhat } from "wagmi/dist/chains";
import { CurrencyDollarIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import { useGlobalState } from "~~/services/store/store";
import { getTargetNetwork } from "~~/utils/scaffold-eth";

export default function NativeCurrencyPrice() {
  const nativeCurrencyPrice = useGlobalState(state => state.nativeCurrencyPrice);

  return (
    <div className="flex space-x-2 pointer-events-auto">
      {nativeCurrencyPrice > 0 && (
        <div className="btn btn-primary btn-sm font-normal cursor-auto">
          <CurrencyDollarIcon className="h-4 w-4 mr-0.5" />
          <span>{nativeCurrencyPrice}</span>
        </div>
      )}
      {getTargetNetwork().id === hardhat.id && <Faucet />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use auto import that caused the wrong path.

instead of this path

```
import { hardhat } from "wagmi/dist/chains";
```

use this path

```
import { hardhat } from "wagmi/chains";
```